# Customizarion of OpenCart E-commerce application

Tags: php, html, e-commerce

I have downloaded opencart e-commerce application and trying to modify the index.php page but I am unable to see html coding of that page only php coding is visible. I am newbie for php please help

Comment: What is the name of your e-commerce application

Comment: Go to view folder where you will find all the html part

Comment: OpenCart open source e-commerce application

Comment: hello sunil it contains the .tpl file

Comment: when i view page source in browser it shows the complete html with php code in the same index.php file but when i open this file in editor it shows only php part of it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure php is installed, enabled. Restart server.

For opencart, html coding is in the view directory into .tpl files.

You should not touch index.php